# Xcode error with UINavigationController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uinavigationcontroller

So what I am trying to do here is press a button and it will switch to the next view controller, but the program crashes after I press the button and shows:

```
return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));Thread      1, Queue : com.apple.main-thread
```

I use segue as push.

When I use segue as modal it doesn't crash.

I did some research online saying "make sure I don't have duplicate relationships"

Is the problem cause by the same name?

I started programming with C# and I know that every control has an ID name, but Xcode doesn't seem to have the ID name.

The two pictures are the relationships of two view controller and one of them is the page that it pops up after the app crashes.

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

[image: image3]

Comment: Go into breakpoints (Upper left corner, just above your files, looks like a right arrow), press the plus in the lower left corner, select Exception Breakpoint and add it, then re run the app. Should give you a better idea of what's going wrong.

Comment: Yes, I did see the errors, thank you. But would you be able to solve it for me please? I searched online and couldn't find solution for that. The errors are Scene is unreachable due to lack of entry points and does not have an identifier for runtime access via -instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:.  and  Segues initiated directly from view controllers must have an identifier for use with -[UIViewController performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:]

Comment: You seem to have 2 arrows coming from the navigation controller to its initial controller. What are those (I'm assuming that the controller all the way to the left is a navigation controller)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Xcode: "Scene is unreachable due to lack of entry points" but can't find it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13531035/xcode-scene-is-unreachable-due-to-lack-of-entry-points-but-cant-find-it)

Comment: As Rick mentioned you have the entry point set to the first UIViewController as the arrow points to it.  It should be set to the UINavigationController before it.  Just move the arrow back to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select your `UINavigationController` from the `storyboard` and from the right side menu, as seen in the picture below, tick the `is Initial View Controller` button.
Then try to run your app again and tell if it works.
Good Luck

[image: is_initial_viewcontroller]

Now choose your `UINavigationController` and as seen from the picture below, drag the circle from `root view controller` and drop it in your `FirstViewController` and try to run again:)

[image: root_view_controller]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I ticked the "is initial view controller" and when I run the program, it shows me a black screen

Comment: But I can still see the battery level and the time on the top

Comment: @Rain Try the editted answer and lets see what happens.