# Error in main.storyboard

Tags: xcode, storyboard

> Main.storyboard: warning: Unsupported Configuration: Scene is
>   unreachable due to lack of entry points and does not have an
>   identifier for runtime access via
>   -instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:.

I'm getting this error all the time, and don't know how to fix it, it happens all the time when I try to create second View Controller. Please help.

P.S I'm new in Swift, and Xcode.

Comment: i think you use storyBoard Auto Layout, check your Constraint for aligning objects, reset and try again

Comment: possible duplicate of [Xcode: "Scene is unreachable due to lack of entry points" but can't find it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13531035/xcode-scene-is-unreachable-due-to-lack-of-entry-points-but-cant-find-it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have this error because you've added a new view controller which is not connected to another one via the segue and there is no Storyboard Id set up so you cannot create an instance of it at runtime.

The solution is to create a segue or if you going to initialise it at runtime select the view controller and in identity inspector insert some name to Storyboard Id text field.