# “uiframework“ is unreachable because it has no entry points, and no identifier for runtime access

Tags: swift, objective-c, xcode, macos, xcode-storyboard

I have built a framework in Xcode that I use in multiple projects. The framework has a storyboard that I load conditionally.

I am a stickler about eliminating compiler warnings and I have just 1 warning in my entire project:

```
“uiframework“ is unreachable because it has no entry points, and no identifier for runtime access via -[NSStoryboard instantiateControllerWithIdentifier:] [9]
```

I don't understand the warning.

I am instantiating the storyboard in my code like this:

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithIdentifier:@"com.foo.uiframework"];
NSStoryboard *sb = [NSStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"uiframework" bundle:bundle];

// if no identities then show welcome view
if (identities.size() == 0) {
    welcomeVC = [sb instantiateControllerWithIdentifier:@"Welcome"];
    self.view.window.contentViewController = welcomeVC;        
} else {
    [Utils activationComplete];
}
```

So what exactly does the compiler want me to do here?

Partial screenshow of Xcode and the storyboard showing there is an entry point and it's the Welcome Scene

[image]

Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39847365/error-unreachable-because-it-has-no-entry-points/43475671) but not the right solution

Comment: Silly question, but worth double-checking: does `[sb instantiateControllerWithIdentifier:@"Welcome"];` actually work?

Comment: Have you included your uiframework in this source file?

Comment: @Alexander it does work. Not a silly question at all.

Comment: @jvarela sorry, not clear to me what you're asking. The framework works, the 2 apps that I build using it both work, just produces this warning at compile time.

Comment: Can you provide a GitHub project where you can reproduce this problem?

Comment: @jvarela - I distilled my project down to something I could put on github and the error went away. That caused me to go back and look at what I removed for github and I found I had a scene in my main storyboard (not the uiframework storyboard that I showed in the screenshot) called `uiframework`. Doh! If you hadn't asked for a github sample I don't know that I would've found it b/c my main storyboard is quite large. Thanks man!